# Thymeleaf unable to read valid object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-rest

I've got a website backed by Spring set up here:

https://github.com/shadd-anderson/Recipe-Site

Everything seems to be working fine for now, but for whatever reason, when I try to access the profile page of a user, it gives me the following error (the id is from a Recipe):

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:139) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.AdditionExpression.executeAddition(AdditionExpression.java:92) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:55) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:107) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.AdditionExpression.executeAddition(AdditionExpression.java:83) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:55) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:107) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.LinkExpression.executeLink(LinkExpression.java:254) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:77) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:67) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringHrefAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(SpringHrefAttrProcessor.java:68) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

None of my other pages do this, and from what I can tell, I'm passing in valid objects to the model. Any clue what could be causing this issue?

Here's my template (minus the top) :

```
<div class="grid-100">

  <div class="recipes">

    <div class="grid-100 row controls section">
      <div class="grid-100">
        <h2 th:text="${user.username}"> Chandra S. </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipes">
      <div class="grid-100 row controls">
        <div class="grid-100">
          <h3> Submitted Recipes: </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-100 row addHover" th:each="recipe : ${createdRecipes}">
        <a href="detail.html">
          <div class="grid-70">
            <a th:text="${recipe.name}" th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}|}" style="display: inline-block;padding-top: 16px;">
              Broiche French Toast with Nutella
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="hoverBlock">
          <div class="grid-30">
            <div class="flush-right">
              <p>
                <a th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/edit|}"> <img th:src="@{images/edit.svg}" height="12px"/> Edit </a>
                <form th:id="'delete' + ${recipeStat.index}" method="post" th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}">
                  <a th:onclick="|document.getElementById('delete${recipeStat.index}').submit();|"><img th:src="@{images/delete.svg}" height="12px"/> Delete </a>
                </form>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="recipes">
      <div class="grid-100 row controls">
        <div class="grid-100">
          <h3> Favorited Recipes: </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div th:if="!${#lists.isEmpty(favoritedRecipes)}">
      <div class="grid-100 row addHover" th:each="recipe : ${favoritedRecipes}">
        <a href="detail.html">
          <div class="grid-70">
            <a th:text="${recipe.name}" th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}|}" style="display: inline-block;padding-top: 16px;">
              Broiche French Toast with Nutella
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="hoverBlock">
          <div class="grid-30">
            <div class="flush-right">
              <p>
                <a th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/edit|}"> <img th:src="@{images/edit.svg}" height="12px"/> Edit </a>
              <form th:id="'delete' + ${recipeStat.index}" method="post" th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}">
                <a th:onclick="|document.getElementById('delete${recipeStat.index}').submit();|"><img th:src="@{images/delete.svg}" height="12px"/> Delete </a>
              </form>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(favoritedRecipes)}">
        <h2>No favorited Recipes</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- recipes -->
</div> <!-- grid-100 --><!-- grid-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share your template?

Comment: There's *something* wrong with your template (`< class="recipes">` midway down), and I suspect automatically reindenting will show you a nesting mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that was missing the div tag. Not sure how I missed that, thank you. But that doesn't seem to be what the issue was

Comment: After commenting out lines to see where the problem is, I've found the issue is in these lines:

`<a th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/edit|}"> <img th:src="@{images/edit.svg}" height="12px"/> Edit </a>
                    <form th:id="'delete' + ${recipeStat.index}" method="post" th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}">
                      <a th:onclick="|document.getElementById('delete${recipeStat.index}').submit();|"><img th:src="@{images/delete.svg}" height="12px"/> Delete </a>
                    </form>`
But I'm not exactly sure how it's not picking up that recipe part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. Evidently the th:each was only replicating the element immediately following the opening `<div>` tag, which was the `<a>` element. So to solve this, I simply created another `<div>` surrounding the entire `<div>` I wanted to replicate and it fixed it